# How to display all data in the database into twig?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.1

**Update :** As Gerry suggested i fix the problem but i can't display nothing using twig. I dump the variable and this is what i get:

```
object(Acme\Bundle\NewBundle\Entity\database)#275 (10) {
 ["id":"Acme\Bundle\NewBundle\Entity\database":private]=> int(2) 
["username":"Acme\Bundle\WebBundle\Entity\database":private]=> string(4) "almighty" 
["password":"Acme\Bundle\NewBundle\Entity\database":private]=> string(7) "blabla" 
["from":"Acme\Bundle\NewBundle\Entity\database":private]=> string(6) "bitola" ....
```

I have tried with:

```
{{% for i in user %}}
{{i.username}} - username
{{i.password}} - password
{{% endfor %}}
```

Still no luck .. the variable has data in it, but it is an object and not an array.So how can i display is  ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to assign the result of the `find()` method to your template. `find()` returns the resulting object (if a match).

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AcmeNewBundle:database')
    ->find($username);

return $this->render('AcmeNewBundle:Default:hello.html.twig',array('user' => $user));
```

If your user object has a property username, you can display it in your template like so:

```
{{ user.username }}
```

Comment: Thank u Gerry this actually help me. But still i cant display the content in the variable..